# Unable to decompress Password Protected Zips

Tags: android, compression, zip, 7-zip, file-corruption

I used Coolpad Note 3 lite with Android version 5.1 (lollipop). Using system's stock file manager I compressed many important files and made password protected zips & password protected nested zips and saved a copy of those zips on pc. These zip files could only be decompressed using coolpad's file manager. But the phone is dead with broken hardware. And I don't have any other coolpad device.

I have tried many zip viewers on android and windows, but they all throw "corrupted file" error. I can't try online zip viewers as the data inside is crucial to me. I will be obliged if someone can help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Zip files are only encrypted of file level, so every viewer should be able to display the contained files. If not, the files are defect or are not zip files at all.

Comment: Golden rule: Don't encrypt backups unless you are sure you can decrypt them. They give a very dangerous false sense of security. A backup is only any good if you can actually use it.

Comment: Without a sample file we can't give an opinion. If you have a small file, post it online.